# What are the drawbacks of Normalized Mutual Information clustering evaluation method?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, evaluation-strategies

What are the drawbacks of Normalized Mutual Information (NMI) clustering evaluation method?
For evaluating what clustering algorithms, is the NMI evaluation method suitable?

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of preference.

If you come with an information theory background, you'll like NMI better. If you come from a classification background, Rand index is pretty much the "accuracy" that you are used to, but on pairs.

Comment: What are the drawbacks and limitations of NMI measure?

Answer (score 0):

In Comparing Community Detection, whenever the ratio between the number of members and the number of clusters is small the Normalized Mutual Information becomes too high which is called *selection bias* problem. This problem caused by inclination of selecting solutions with more clusters (Amelio et al. 2015)

> For evaluating what clustering algorithms, is the NMI evaluation
>   method suitable?

I think this question incomplete.